# How to display weather related information?

Tags: yii, weather

I am working in Yii-php framework. I am creating function which will retrive weather related information from some weather websites suppose weather.com
So in Yii, how to receive weather related information from certain site and display it on view.
Can we make use of webservice for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check This extension [NOAA Weather Extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/noaaweather/)

The NOAA Weather Extension works with data provided by the U.S. National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration (NOAA) and the National Weather Service (NWS). Features include:

1. List item
2. Pre-made weather widgets you can quickly add to your site Data
3. providers that allow full access to raw weather data Intelligent
4. download retry and cache behaviors Unlike proprietary services, all 
       weather data is in the public domain

Comment: Actually sir, my server side is designed in extjs and clieant side is in yii framework. So i need to retrieve data and need to send it in json format to server side. So how to implement this?